# Monogame: "could not load fbx model asset as a non-content file"

Tags: xna, monogame

I recently changed operating systems on my laptop (went from 8.1 to Windows 7). I transferred my game project, and after having to rebuild it (due to Visual Studio 2013 stating it cannot open my project file), I managed to get it to run, but as soon as the code tries to load my cube.fbx model, I get the error in the title.

My settings for the model are as follows:

[image]

And the code for loading (which worked flawlessly before the transfer) is as follows:

```
modelCube = content.Load<Model>("Models/cube");
```

I have no idea what the issue is. All help points to setting the Build Action to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory to "Always". The only clue I can think of is that originally, my project was made for Android, and on this iteration I remade it as a normal Windows project (as for whatever reason, I couldn't get an Android project to work this time).

Thanks in advance. This is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

While I doubt anyone else will have this problem, I figured out the issue. I think Monogame changed the way it loaded assets since the last time I used it. With my install of a newer version, I just had to follow the link below to get it working again.

http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-managing-content